# Loading Stackoverflow dump into Dash

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I use the excellent Dash documentation manager for OS X. It allows for a live search of the SO site. The SO site is dumped, anonymised and available in XML format every 3 months.

Has anyone found a way to load the dump into Dash? And to have it viewable in a presentable format, ideally searchable by tags and perhaps load only a tag-based subset.

http://kapeli.com/dash